# Cannot create a Vulkan device, Try updating your video driver to more recent version

Tags: unreal-engine5, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to open a game which I made in Unreal Engine 5 and build for arm64. When I try to open the game I am getting an error:

```
Cannot create a Vulkan device, Try updating your video driver to more recent version
```

I couldn't figure out which driver is that driver I have gstreamer v4l2.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cannot-creat-a-vulkan-device-try-updating-your-video-driver-to-more-recent-version/261997